# content is overflowing container and overlapping footer on screen reduction

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div above my footer and the content from the footer overlaps its parent div in width and height on smaller mobile screens.

[image: Image of overlapping content]

I have tried every overflow value available, and even limited the height of the child div to 80%.  What I would like to happen is on smaller screens the content stays contained, and centered. I'm not completely sure if this responsive behavior requires a media query, but I thought that Bootstrap would handle this.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/KingdomB/pen/ZEWLbKV)

```css
/* BEGINNING OF CONTACT SECTION STYLING */
#contact {
    background: url(../img/image3.png) no-repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: rgb(233, 233, 233) 4px solid;
    border-bottom: rgb(233, 233, 233) 7px solid;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100vw;
    min-width: 100vw;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 1%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-size: cover;
}

#overlay {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
}
  

#contact form {
    padding: 50px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 30vmax;
    min-width: 20vw;
    float: left;
    left: 8vmax;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3vh;
}

.form-background {
    background-color: rgb(247, 241, 221);
    color: #555;
}

#contact form label {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 100;
}


.hiden-form {
    display: none;
}

.social-widget {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    width: fit-content !important;
    max-width: 100vw;
    left: 9vw;
    max-height: 80%;
}

.ruler {
    width: 35%;
    border:1px solid #3554aa;
    
}

.footer-2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.widget-footer ul,
.widget-footer #menu-footer_2 a,
div .widget-footer p {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size:1.6rem;
    color: rgb(148, 148, 180);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.widget-footer #menu-footer_2 a {
    margin-top: 2vh;
}

footer {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #0f1e49;
    color: white;
}
/* END OF CONTACT DIV STYLING */

/* BEGINNING OF SOCIAL MEDIA ICON STYLING */
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

.text-widget ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

}

i {
    text-align: center !important;
}

a.btn-social,
.btn-social
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    height: 54px;
    line-height: 54px;
    margin: 8px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    width: 54px;
}

.btn-social .fa,.btn-social i
{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all .25s;
}
.btn-social:hover,.btn-social:focus
{
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-social:hover .fa,
.btn-social:focus .fa,
.btn-social:hover i,
.btn-social:focus i {
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.btn-social.btn-xs {
    font-size: 9px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 13px;
    margin: 6px 2px;
    width: 24px;
}

.btn-social.btn-sm {
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 6px 2px;
    width: 36px;
}

.btn-social.btn-lg {
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 72px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 10px 6px;
    width: 72px;
}

.btn-media {
    background-color: #0f1e49;
}

.btn-media:hover {
    background-color: #83c3f3;
}
/* END OF SOCIAL MEDIA ICON STYLING */

footer p {
        font-family: 'Poppins' !important;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 1.4rem;

}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>


  <title>Google Home</title>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto%7CJosefin+Sans:100,300,400,500"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,800;1,400;1,600;1,800&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediastyle.css">

</head>

<body>
   <section id="contact">
    <div id="overlay" class="container">
      <div class="social-widget">
        <div class="widgets_width col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-7 footer-1 widget-footer">
          <div id="tmc_info-3" class="widget widget_tmc_info">
            <h4 class="widget-title">MORE ABOUT US</h4>
            <hr class="ruler">
            <div class="footer_text text-widget">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna ali qua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="socials text-widget">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn-social btn-twitter btn-lg btn-media">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn-social btn-twitter btn-lg btn-media">
                    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn-social btn-twitter btn-lg btn-media">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn-social btn-twitter btn-lg btn-media">
                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widgets_width col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-4 footer-2 widget-footer">
          <div class="widget widget_nav_menu">
            <h4 class="widget_title no_stripe">QUICK LINKS</h4>
            <hr class="ruler">
            <div class="menu-footer_2-container ">
              <ul id="menu-footer_2" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-747" class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#">> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-775" class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#">> About</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-860" class="menu-item">
                  <a href="#">> Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <form class="hiden-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Your Name<span>*</span></label>
            <input class="form-control form-background" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Your Email<span>*</span></label>
            <input class="form-control form-background" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type your message here<span>*</span></label>
            <textarea class="form-control form-background" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-md form-background">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p class="text-center">Google Home Copyright &copy; 2020</p>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="assets/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason your #contact section has a height of 50vh? This won't work well with the content because if the content exceeds that height, it will overflow the container (or if you add overflow: auto on it, creates a scrollbar). Also, on wider but shorter screens, it isn't as responsive or reasonable in terms of user experience. Does it have to be 50vh, or can you use "min-height: 50vh" which will allow the container to expand its height so that all elements are contained?

Comment: @Xenvi That suggestion makes sense, but it did not work.

Comment: I will mess with your codepen, I just wanted to make sure that having the #contact container more than only 50vh was okay for what you are trying to accomplish (=

Comment: @Xenvi I already solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Xenvi suggests, the #contact height required a min value instead of a max value.  What ultimately fixed the issue in addition to Xenvi's suggestion is removing the absolute positioning from .social-widget.